# r gbm package summary function performing erroring

Tags: r, gbm

I am trying to use the gbm package within r, and am having problems with the summary function.  Hoping that someone can help out. My code is as follows:

```
library(ISLR)
Caravan$Purchase <- ifelse(Caravan$Purchase == "Yes", 1, 0)
train_index <- 1:1000
train <- Caravan[train_index, ]
test <- Caravan[-train_index, ]

library(gbm)
set.seed(1234)
boost <- gbm(Purchase ~ ., data = train, n.trees=400, shrinkage =0.01,
             distribution = "bernoulli")
summary(boost)
```

I get the following error message with traceback:

```
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : need finite 'xlim' values
5.
plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...)
4.
barplot.default(rel.inf[i[cBars:1]], horiz = TRUE, col = rainbow(cBars, start = 3/6, end = 4/6), names = object$var.names[i[cBars:1]], xlab = "Relative influence", ...)
3.
barplot(rel.inf[i[cBars:1]], horiz = TRUE, col = rainbow(cBars, start = 3/6, end = 4/6), names = object$var.names[i[cBars:1]], xlab = "Relative influence", ...)
2.
summary.gbm(boost)
1.
summary(boost)
```

I have tried using the workaround here: http://www.samuelbosch.com/2015/09/workaround-ntrees-is-missing-in-r.html to no avail.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1: Confirmed error occurs in R 3.5.0, but does not occur in 3.4.4.

Comment: Your code runs without error on my machine (R v3.4.1, gbm 2.1.3, ISLR 1.2), the plot also renders correctly.

Comment: Hmmm, OK, maybe I am having a problem since I am on R 3.5.0